# Can you find if a number is fibonacci without looping or using a square root?

Tags: java, algorithm

doing some practice technical tests for interviews but I have been asked to find if a number is in the Fibonacci sequence without using a loop or square root. I have done an implementation with loops but does not count. so how am I supposed to go about it unless I have infinite if statements?

Comment: Recursion isn’t usually considered a loop.

Comment: @VictorWilson: Of course it's a loop.  How could it be otherwise?  That's how functional programming languages like lisp are able to loop without using an explicit loop construct like `for` or `while`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is a loop but as thye said, it is often not considered a loop. For example in homework questions that say _"dont use loops"._

Comment: Create a list, or download one, of fibanacci numbers up to Integer.MAX_VALUE and save it in a text file. Then have your program check if your element is in the list. I'm sure there is a loop in there though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I submit a language like Lisp cannot iterate through lists of items; it can only recurse through them. Maybe it’s a semantic difference - while the end result is the same, they occupy different sectors of my brain.

Answer (score 2):

This may seem like cheating, but if it isn't `1` then check whether `Math.round(x * 2.23606797749979))` when squared gives you `5*x*x+4` or `5*x*x-4`.

The reason why is that 5 times a Fibonacci number +- 4 has to be a perfect square.  And if `x` is at all large, the only number which, when squared, could possibly do it is the closest integer to `x*sqrt(5)`.  And "at all large" works out to be larger than 1.

Comment: I do wonder how knowing this makes one a better candidate in a technical interview, unless the position requires an extensive math background.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is a terrible interview question.  If I was asked it, that would be a strike against my interviewer.